# Rotation of a bitmap matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, geometry

Let A be a 3x3 matrix (of black and white pixels) :

```
A = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])
```

corresponding to

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

**How to perform a 90° rotation with the centre being the middle "1" of the matrix ?**

Comment: Look into [`np.rot90`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) ?

Comment: @Divakar Great! Is there similar thing for horizontal / vertical symmetry ?

Comment: @Basj  Is it so hard to go level up link? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html